# Assembly language based on 8051

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, 8051

Here's my code for a simple 24-shot clock:

```
$MOD51  ; This includes 8051 definitions for the Metalink assembler

start:
SETB P3.5
MOV P1,#0A4H
CLR P3.5


mov p1,#99h
LCALL wait

mov p1,#0b0h
LCALL wait

mov p1,#0a4h
LCALL wait

mov p1,#0f9h
LCALL wait


mov p1,#0c0h
LCALL wait

SETB P3.5
MOV P1,#0F9H
CLR P3.5


mov p1,#90h
LCALL wait

MOV A,#08H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait

MOV A,#07H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait

MOV A,#06H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait

MOV A,#05H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait

MOV A,#04H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait

MOV A,#03H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait

MOV A,#02H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait

MOV A,#01H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait


MOV A,#00H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait

SETB P3.5
MOV P1,#0C0H
CLR P3.5
MOV A,#09H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait

MOV A,#08H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait

MOV A,#07H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait

MOV A,#06H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait

MOV A,#05H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait

MOV A,#04H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait

MOV A,#03H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait

MOV A,#02H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait

MOV A,#01H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait


MOV A,#00H
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
LCALL wait



Lcall loop_1

wait:
MOV R0,#0

MOV R2,#8
delay:
DJNZ R0, delay

DJNZ R2,delay
RET

display:
INC A
MOVC A,@A+PC
RET
DB 0C0H ;0
DB 0F9H ;1
DB 0A4H ;2
DB 0B0H ;3
DB 99H ;4
DB 92H ;5
DB 82H ;6
DB 0F8H ;7
DB 80H ;8
DB 90H ;9
DB 88H ;A
DB 83H ;B
DB 0C6H ;C
DB 0A1H ;D
DB 86H ;E
DB 8EH ;F


loop_1:
Lcall loop_1
END
```

I have an issue where I need to incorporate a push-button as a stop/start button for a basic two-digit countdown timer. Upon starting or resetting the timer, it will show 99 and will not count down until the push-button is pressed. Once the timer is running, pressing the same button will halt the timer. However, when the timer is halted, pushing the button again will resume and continue the countdown. Note that the push-button is connected to port 3.2

I have tried to implement a loop for the button but it won't work.

Comment: Do you realize that `loop_1: Lcall loop_1` pushes a return address onto the stack each iteration of that busy-wait loop?

Comment: That stackoverflow caused by relentless pushing without balanced popping will almost certainly wipe out all of your memory in short order.  Use `Ljmp`  for that one  there instead, and also including the initial reference to it from further above, since it doesn't use (or pop) a return address at all.